Excel Interop working locally but not working on the server
I have code that opens an existing spreadsheet, loads it with values, calculates then pulls back the resulting values.  On my local machine it works fine.  On the server, I get an error:
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8001010a The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)).
Both machines have the same version of Office 365 installed on them.  The error occurs when I make the call to my function (before it hits the first line of code).  The class is running in a .NET 7.0 project, being consumed by a Blazor application running in IIS on the server.  Any ideas?
TIA
Here is the code (for the most part):
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new();
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
           try
           {
               // Load a workbook from the file.
               oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(modelPath);
               oXL.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
               oSheet = oWB.Sheets[1];
               oSheet.Activate();
               //oXL.Visible = true;
//******Do logic here
               oWB.Close(false);
               System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWB);
               System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oSheet);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw new Exception(stepsTaken + ex.Message);
           }
           finally
           {
               oXL.Application.Quit();
               oXL.Quit();
               System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oXL);
               oSheet = null;
               oWB = null;
               oXL = null;
               GC.Collect();
               GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
               GC.Collect();
           }


You shouldn't be using Excel interop in a web host.

Excel COM interop is not designed for server scenarios without a console, only for GUI scenarios. Use OpenXML instead

The issue is that I need the updates I write to the spreadsheet to calculate and return new values to me realtime.  DevExpres has a great object but it doesn't recognize XLOOKUP.  Interop works fine on my machine but not in the server environment.  EPPlus and ClosedXML don't recalculate.
